# Loading a character into register immediately. MIPS

Tags: mips

My teacher was saying that you can simply just load a character into a register like so:

```
li $s2 "A"
li $s1 "0"
```

Except, when I load my file into Qtspim it keeps throwing me a syntax error for it. Does anyone know if my teacher told me a lie, and if so, how to go about loading a character into a register by immediate ways. I know how to do it if the character is in data already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your teacher is correct in that it's possible to use character literals. But either he gave you the wrong syntax for it, or you misunderstood him when he explained it.

The correct syntax would be to use single quotes (instead of double quotes like in your examples):

```
li $s2, 'A'
li $s1, '0'
```

Note that you were also missing the commas between the operands for `li`.

Comment: Maybe you did something else wrong then. Single-quoted character literals work just fine for me both in QtSpim and PCSpim.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for literals, (both values and refs...)

```
.data

hello:  .asciiz "Hello, world!"

my_character : .byte 'a'

.text


li $s1, '0'
li $s2, 'A'

la $a0, my_character
la $a0, hello
```

try in MARS:
when loaded '0' you will see 30Hex, as ascii is 48.

[image]